# How do I import a specific branch of a Git repository to another repository?

Tags: git, github

I have an organization on GitHub, in which two repositories exist. One is a C++ library, and the other is an HTML repository.

Let's assume that they are located in the following repositories.
https://github.com/MyOrganization/mylibrary.git
https://github.com/MyOrganization/myorganization.github.io.git

I would like to import only branch `gh-pages` of `milibrary.git` to `myorganization.github.io.git` with its history being kept, but I do not know how to do it. Would anyone kindly tell me appropriate commands?

My motivation is to migrate the home page of http://myorganization.github.io/MyLibrary/ to http://myorganization.github.io/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the next steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/MyOrganization/myorganization.github.io website
cd website
git pull https://github.com/MyOrganization/mylibrary.git gh-pages
git push
```

This will download your `gh-pages` branch and merge it into your default branch from website repository.

You may have some conflicts to solve.

Comment: I had to also use `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories` to get this to work.

Answer (score 4):

Try -

```
git clone https://github.com/MyOrganization/myorganization.github.io.git
cd myorganization.github.io.git
git remote add other https://github.com/MyOrganization/mylibrary.git
git fetch other
git checkout -b gh-pages --track other/gh_pages
git remote remove other
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, but probably my question was ambiguous. I wanted to import `gh-pages` of `mylibrary.git` to `master` of `my organization.github.io.git`.